# TextBox leave event in ContextMenuStrip not firing

Tags: c#, forms, textbox, visual-studio-2015, contextmenustrip

I have a ContextMenuStrip containing two TextBoxes.

I want the validate the text inserted in a TextBox by using the TextBox.Leave event, but whenever I click outside the TextBox or the ContextMenuStrip, the event does not fire. The same for other events, like Validate, Enter etc. However, some events like MouseEnter or Click work.

Do you have any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: The TextBox object is destroyed before it can generate the Leave event.  Also the reason why the MSDN documentation for the LostFocus event sternly warns to never use it and why it is hidden in the designer.  Simple workarounds are using the TextBox.Disposed event or the ContextMenuStrip.Closing event.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround using the LostFocus event on this post:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/79fe930b-880a-4e18-8e06-def459cec29d/how-to-detect-when-toolstriptextbox-loses-focus?forum=winforms

Answer (score 0):

Just create `LostFocus` event handler manually. **NOTE- `LostFocus` event is not showing in VS designer.**

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        toolStripTextBox1.LostFocus += ToolStripTextBox1_LostFocus;
    }
    private void ToolStripTextBox1_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Your code!!!
    }
```